# Why i can't login after register in function views but not with class based views?

Tags: django, formview, django-class-based-views

I have a registration form and i need when the user register be login automatically, i can get it with a function view but when i try with a class based view it does not works

My function view:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = UserCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            new_user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'],password=request.POST['password1'])
            login(request, new_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/contadores/index")
    else:
        form = UserCreateForm()
    return render_to_response("contadores/register.html", {
        'form': form,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and my class based view:

```
class RegisterView(FormView):
    form_class = UserCreateForm
    template_name = 'contadores/register.html'
    success_url = '/contadores/create/'

    def form_valid(self,form):
        user = form.save()
        user = authenticate(username=self.request.POST['username'],password=self.request.POST['password'])
        login(request,user)
        return super(RegisterView,self).form_valid(form)

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contadores/create')
        else:
            return super(RegisterView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Obviously when I try with the function view i disabled the class based view and the url and vice versa, the error that i got with the class based view is:

> Exception Type:   MultiValueDictKeyError
>    Exception Value:  "'password'"

What is wrong with my class based view?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting can be circumvented by using `.get` on the POST dict.

```
self.request.POST.get('password', '')
```

Using `.get` will enable you to provide a default value if the key you're trying to access is not found furthermore it will not raise the Exception.

Other than that you seem to have two differing password fields, in your function based view you have `self.request.POST['password1']` and in your CBV you have `self.request.POST['password']`.